# Regular expression for a url with no www and with .html in the end?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this url:

```
http://thisjs.blogspot.co.il/2015/01/blog-post_7.html
```

And in javascript i have this pattern to check for it's validity, which returns false for some reason, what is missing here?

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
            '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
            '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
            '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\d%_.~+#!]*)*'+ // port and path
            '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
            '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
            if(!pattern.test(str)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
```

I want true on the url i mentioned above? where do i look first?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have:

```
'(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+#!]*)*'+ // port and path
```

i.e. `\\d` instead of `\d` otherwise you are just matching literal `d` instead of a digit.